# Docker не монтирует volume postgresql на windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker-compose

При запуске docker-compose, появляется проблема с монтированием папки с данными postgres. Проблема возникает только на windows 10, на macos все работает корректно

Docker-compose

```
postgres:
 image: postgres:12-alpine
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 env_file:
   - .env
```

Ошибка

````
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Moscow
creating configuration files ... ok
2020-08-13 10:49:37.512 MSK [51] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2020-08-13 10:49:37.512 MSK [51] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
running bootstrap script ... ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Лучше монтировать volume, которые делает сам docker `db:/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

Если шарить с хостом `./database` -- нужно разбираться с правами.

Если шарить и с виндой -- будет работать медленней.